# Serializing the function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javaScript object having some value. I need to call a function as many times as the object has the value. Look at the code snipet

```
for(var i=0; i < scroll["altscroll"]; i++){
    more_alt_leftajaxsearchcategory(0, 0, element=false, back = true);
}
```

The called function loads some element through ajax method and append it to the body. 
The problem is that when loop executes the function is called instantaneously but the called function returned result not in the order expected. For example if function is called 3 times and if returned result in last calling is smaller in size then it appends first in the body after that the other returned result is appended.
Can we serialize the function call so that it does not call another function until the first one completes.
The called function code snipet:

```
var pageCount = 1;  
function more_leftajaxsearchcategory(locval,pageid, element, back){

    var offsetCount = pageCount * 10;
      var dataString = jQuery("#leftformid").serialize();   
      jQuery.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        type:'POST',
        data: 'action=leftmenusearchcategory'+'&locationval='+locval+'&numb='+offsetCount+'&'+dataString,           
        beforeSend: function(){jQuery('body').append('<p class="overBck"><img alt="Loading..." src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="margin-top:25%;"></p>'); },
        success:function(results, status)
        {       
                jQuery(".book_results").append(results);
                if(results == 'Sorry no results found. Please search again.'){
                    jQuery('.sidebar_loadMore').hide();
                    pageCount =1;
                }
                jQuery('.overBck').remove();
                 short_deals_attr();

        }

      });
    pageCount++;
}
```

I have removed the unnesessory code. You can also look at the live site [Bestofthebrunch](http://bestofthebrunch.co.uk/dev/search-listing)

Comment: In order to help you sequence your Ajax calls, you will have to show us the code where you make the Ajax call as the problem cannot be fixed just with the code you've included.  The handling of the Ajax call itself needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible way that I found to serialize the function call in this case is a recursive call on the success of the previous one.

```
more_alt_leftajaxsearchcategory(0, 0, element=false, back = true, scroll["altscroll"] -1);
```

and updated the called function on success of Ajax by

```
 if(back && loadtimes > 0){
    more_alt_leftajaxsearchcategory(0, 0, element=false, back = true, loadtimes-1 ); 
}
```

like this...

```
var pageCount = 1;  
function more_leftajaxsearchcategory(locval,pageid, element, back, times){
var offsetCount = pageCount * 10;
  var dataString = jQuery("#leftformid").serialize();   
  jQuery.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
    type:'POST',
    data: 'action=leftmenusearchcategory'+'&locationval='+locval+'&numb='+offsetCount+'&'+dataString,           
    beforeSend: function(){jQuery('body').append('<p class="overBck"><img alt="Loading..." src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="margin-top:25%;"></p>'); },
    success:function(results, status)
    {       
            jQuery(".book_results").append(results);
            if(results == 'Sorry no results found. Please search again.'){
                jQuery('.sidebar_loadMore').hide();
                pageCount =1;
            }

            if(back && loadtimes > 0){
                more_alt_leftajaxsearchcategory(0, 0, element=false, back = true, loadtimes-1 ); 
            }

            jQuery('.overBck').remove();
             short_deals_attr();

    }

  });
pageCount++;
}
```

In this method the function `more_leftajaxsearchcategory` is not called immediately without caring of the response of previous call. The function is called only when the first one get the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add addtional param to pass in a callback that would be called when the ajax complete its work, then you can achieve something like this.

I'd use setTimeout with random length to fake as an ajax call:

```js
var inserial = function(times) {
  var count = 0;
  function delay() {
    var cur = count;
    var length = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1) * 500;
    $('<div>').text('#' + cur + ' will complete in ' + length).appendTo($('body'));
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Somthing in success ajax callback.
      $('<div>').text('#' + cur + 'Done.').appendTo($('body'));
    
      // Then call it to start next ajax load.
      done();
    }, length);
    count++;
  }
  function done() {
    if (count === times) {
      $('<div>').text('All done').appendTo($('body'));
      return;
    }
    delay();
  }
  
  
  // Your function, which aceepts a callback function.
  delay();
};

inserial(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you love to embrace new techs, try Promise, it's a ES2015 feature while there are already libs implements it, it makes you easy to start all loading process at the same time, while keeps the order of the elements.

But you may need to learn its idea first, [JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) should be a good start.

```js
var delay = function(id, cb) {
  var length = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1) * 500;
  $('<div>').text('#' + id + ' will complete in ' + length).appendTo($('body'));
  
  // Wrap you ajax into promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
        
          // This will be called in ajax's success callback. 
          resolve(id);    
        
      }, length);  
  });
};

var i, arr = [];
// These function will all start to execute.
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  arr[i] = delay(i);
}

// But their results will be guranteed to put in order.
var sequence = Promise.resolve();
arr.reduce(function(seq, item) {
  // 
  return seq.then(function() {
    // the promise return from delay will get the resolved id as parameter.
    return item;
  }).then(function(id) {
    
      // This is the commands in origin ajax's succes callback.
      $('<div>').text('#' + id + 'Complete.').appendTo($('body'));
  });
  
}, sequence);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.0/es6-shim.js"></script>
```